# Pegar o value de um select e jogar no js

Tags: javascript, html

Olá. Bom, estou aprendendo programação ainda, então sou bem iniciante.

Eu quero pegar a value selecionada pelo usuario:

```
<select class="selecionar" id="teste" name="teste">
  <option default disabled="disabled">Selecione uma opção</option>
  <option value="teste1.html">opção 1</option>
  <option value="teste2.html">opção 2</option>
</select>
```

e jogar a value selecionada em uma ajax no js:

```
var pegar = document.getElementById("teste").value;

$.ajax({
    url: pegar,
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    }
```

porém, ele só pega a primeira opção da lista, não a que o usuário selecionou.

não sei explicar direito, desculpem.

Comment: use assim já que está usando jquery: `var pegar = $( "#teste" ).val();`

Comment: Não adiantou. Ele continua pegando somente o primeiro (que no caso é o teste1.html). se eu seleciono a opção 2 (teste2.html) não adianta, ele continua no 1.

Comment: então deve estar fazendo algo errado no seu código, coloca todo o código na pergunta, porque isso que sugeri funciona bem, veja aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/gspu5dbc/1/

Comment: Consegui! eu fiz "igual" ao teu. porém, ao inves do alert, eu criei uma variável  e depois setei ela no lugar do alert. obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer de duas formas: apenas com javascript ou usando a biblioteca JQuery.

**Javascript**

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var option = this.selectedOptions[0];
  var texto = option.textContent;

  console.log(texto);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>item 2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var option = this.selectedOptions[0];
  var texto = option.textContent;

  console.log(texto);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>item 2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
```